# make variables accessible to multiple actions in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a set of boolean symbols, inside a controller action

These are currently in 1 action, in the following format

```
def my_action
  setup_stages = [:data_entry_completed, :data_validation_completed]
  setup_stages.each do |stage|
    do stuff
  end
end
```

I've noticed that I need to make use of these symbols in another action but do not want to replicate them. Is there a way to make this list accessible to multiple actions in the controller so that I can iterate through them without having the list twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define them as [constant](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html):

```
class MyController < AplicationController

  SETUP_STAGES = [:data_entry_completed, :data_validation_completed]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally define it as an instance variable:

```
class MyClass 

  def initialize 
    @setup_stages = [:data_entry_completed, :data_validation_completed]
  end

  def do_action 
    @setup_stages.each do |stage|
       # do stuff
    end
  end

  def show_stages
    puts @setup_stages.to_s
  end

end

x = MyClass.new
x.do_action
x.show_stages
```

A constant is also a good way of defining this but should not be altered, so if for whatever reason you want to add other options to the array dynamically you would be able to do this with an instance variable.